# Choice,Rollback,catch Exception strategy in mule

Tags: exception, mule, rollback

I need to take data from one queue and need to place data in other queue.

Exception handling strategy: if destination queue is down need to place data in source queue. If destination queue is up and anything go wrong in between then need to write to other queue(to do not loose the message). To achieve this I'm using choice, rollback and catch exception strategy.

in rollback's when condition: #[exception.causedBy(java.net.UnknownHostException) ||exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException)||exception.causedBy(org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)]

if other than this occur go to catch : I'm leaving when condition as blank but problem is if error occurs directly console coming to catch not executing rollback. and I'm loosing the message from source.

Please suggest me on this.., thanks in advance..,

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be save the initial payload ( jms message ) at the start of the flow:

```
<flow name="flow.jms.in">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="queue.in"/>
        <set-variable variableName="initialJmsPayload" value="#[payload]"/>
        .....
</flow>
```

So in your catch estrategy or anywhere you can get this var "initialJmsPayload" depending on your scope : session, application, outbound,etc

In your catch strategy you could print the #[message] in orider to see all variables in message :

```
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=36927f80-66c1-11e5-af11-34e6d74f92e6
  payload=com.mycompany.Object
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    ....
    MULE_MESSAGE_ID=ID:A25MD001-57147-1443541361491-11:1:1:1:1
    ...
    OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
  SESSION scoped properties:
    myVar=java.lang.String
}
```